# How to display price of a variable WooCommerce product?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the price (later on normal price next to sale price) of a variable WooCommerce product. The code is inserted into a block (similar to widget) which is placed on my landing page. Unfortunately my price div is not working/showing anything :(

Could you please help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="variant">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="3"><span>3 Natural Energy-Riegel</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="12" checked="checked"><span>12 Natural Energy-Riegel</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="24"><span>24 Natural Energy-Riegel</span></label>
</div>

<div id="price"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_product_price() {

var $radio = $('input[name=toggle]:checked');

    if ($radio.attr("id") == 3) {
        $_product = wc_get_product('297');
        $price = $_product->get_price();
    } elseif ($radio.attr("id") == 12) {
        $_product = wc_get_product('299');
        $price = $_product->get_price();
    } else ($radio.attr("id") == 24) {
        $_product = wc_get_product('300');
        $price = $_product->get_price();
    }

document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = $price;

}
</script>
```

Comment: There are lots of typos in your code. Did you write it yourself?

Comment: As for ES6, there are no thin arrows like `->`. And `elseif` is actually `else if`. This code of yours looks like a `PHP SCRIPT`. But not a `JAVASCRIPT` I don't use **Woocommerce** but, this script of yours does not make sense at all.

Comment: Hi Rüzgar, thanks a lot for your quick feedback! It's written by myself (please excuse my mistakes, I'm just starting to get into JS). Unfortunately I couldn't find a method to get the product price of an WooCommerce product via Javascript, but I'm still searching because I can't use PHP in the advanced section of my theme (like custom css) and in the functions.php it would force the page to reload :(

Comment: Without reloading, you can't get a value from the database. **UNLESS** you use `AJAX` or the values that you need are loaded on page load. But if you are using an AJAX search on your page, then you can find a way to clone this behaviour. It is a long shot but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)